# how can I write string inside a string in Squeak?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

My method receives  a String argument.

That String represents source code, which can contain another string.

The problem is that now I want to have a quoted string inside a quoted string, and the compiler doesn't accept it.

```
obj mymethod:
  'mymethod: arg
   Transcript show: 'code to make noise';cr. "This is the method code"
  '.
```

How can I write string inside a string (i.e., how can I include a string quote character `'` inside a string) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape single quote in string with another single quote. So you have to do:

```
obj mymethod:
  'mymethod: arg
   Transcript show: ''code to make noise'';cr. "This is the method code"
  '.
```